# Conditional subtraction

Tags: calculated-column, reporting-services

I need to create a calculation that basically is a subtraction between two fields (2 date fields). However it should be done only if a 3rd field is equal to a value of 5 or 6.

- My first field is director approval date
- My second field is finance approval date
- My third field is either 5,6,7 or 8

I know this can be done in Excel but in my case I need this to be done in a calculated column in a SharePoint list.

Comment: So, apply your Excel skills, only limitation is SharePoint Formulas can not use all Excel functions. See [this list](http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List) for functions available in SharePoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formula will be something like this:

```
=IF(OR([Column3]="5", [Column3]="6"), [director approval date]-[finance approval date], "-")
```

Here is the reference
[Example of common formulas](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Examples-of-common-formulas-D81F5F21-2B4E-45CE-B170-BF7EBF6988B3)

Comment: Nice example, nice link. I didn't know about the OR function. Luis, you might like to check exactly what is in your source columns using IF and a test column. Test for 5 and output "yes" or "no" etc.

Comment: Hi Luis, check now. After adding 5 and 6 in double quotes (for e.g. "5", "6") the formula started working. I edited the formula in above answer. I tested it and its working.

Comment: yes, now it works

Comment: what if I want to add the following an additional condition? My fourth field is less than 500

Comment: The formula will be some thing like this: =IF(AND([Column4]<"500",OR([Column 3]="5",[Column 3]="6")),[Date 2]-[Date 1],"-")